# c stdout print without new line?

Tags: c, printf, stdout

i   want   to   print  "CLIENT>"  on  stdout  in c, without new line.
printf("CLIENT>");
does  not print enything.
how do i solve this?

```
int main (){
printf("CLIENT>");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 9):

Try [`fflush(stdout);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) after your `printf`.

You can also investigate `setvbuf` if you find yourself calling `fflush` frequently and want to avoid having to call it altogether.  Be aware that if you are writing lots of output to standard output then there will probably be a performance penalty to using `setvbuf`.

Comment: he asked without a newline.  printf still prints a newline regardless of flushing.

Comment: `printf` does not include a newline automatically.  For example, you can write `printf("abc");printf("def");` and the string `abcdef` will appear (with no newlines in the middle or at the end) on the standard output.

Answer (score 5):

Call `fflush` after `printf()`:

```
int main (){
    printf("CLIENT>");
    fflush( stdout );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On some compilers/runtime libraries (usually the older ones) you have to call [fflush](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) to have the data physically written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
  printf("CLIENT>");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

If the data has newline in the end, usually `fflush` isn't needed - even on the older systems.

Comment: "Usually the old ones"? Not true. It's a feature known as buffering which is employed in most if not all modern environments, and which in fact might be *lacking* in older systems (although I can't think of any!)