# Wierd output for string operation IDEONE

Tags: c, string, output

Can someone tell me why this happens, what is wrong here:

I have to print a part of string where starting location and length of string to be printed is given in input.

PROBLEM:
When i run it in devC++ everything runs fine and ok output.
When i run it in IDEONE, the code produces no output [from the character array] unless i print the whole string using printf("%s\n",abc);

---> When i don't use printf("%s\n",abc); http://ideone.com/BMjCku

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    long long int q;
    int length=0;
    scanf("%lld",&q);   
    while(q--)
    {
        int loc,cutlength=0,k=0,pos,plen=0;

        char abc[100001],save[100001],c;
        while(1)
        {
            scanf("%c",&c);
            if(c=='+' || c=='?')
                break;  
        }
        if (c=='+')
        {
            scanf("%d",&loc); pos=loc;
            cutlength=length-loc;
            for(int i=loc;i<=length-loc;i++)
                save[k++]=abc[i];
            scanf("%c",&c);
            while(!isalpha(c))
                scanf("%c",&c);
            while(1)
            {
                if(!isalpha(c))
                    break;
                abc[loc++]=c; length++; 
                scanf("%c",&c);
            }
            length+=pos+cutlength;
            for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
                abc[loc++]=save[i];
        }

        else if(c == '?')
        {
            if(&abc[0] == &abc[0]);
            scanf("%d%d",&loc,&plen);
            loc--;
            while(plen--)
                printf("%c",abc[loc++]);
            printf("\n");
            //printf("%s\n",abc);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---> When i use printf("%s\n",abc); http://ideone.com/Y6Sh5K

Comment: Suggestion #1: always test the return value of `scanf()`: `if (scanf(WHATEVER, &#1, ..., &#n) != n) /* error */;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [c stdout print without new line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431425/c-stdout-print-without-new-line)

Comment: @n.m. but this code has `printf("\n");`.

Comment: @pmg i checked each input and output at various stages and everything not associated with character was printed but not the char[taken from the array]. Here is the program with tested return values... still no output http://ideone.com/RaRJgl

Comment: I haven’t read the full code, but you’re reading from `abc` before anything is assigned to it. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: what on earth is `if(&abc[0] == &abc[0]);` meant to do

Comment: @MattMcNabb that is absolutely not needed. i just did that to check whether accessing the array is doing something.

Comment: @deadFish that code does not access the array

Comment: @n.m. but this code has `printf("\n");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the `c == '?'` block uses the array `abc` when it is uninitialized.

It seems as if you think the data put in `abc` by the `c == '+'` block should remain when you go into the next loop iteration. However that is not true: the `abc` is local to the block opened by `while(q--) {`, so each loop iteration it is destroyed and recreated.

Possibly it appears to work on Dev-C++ because that does no checking, and re-uses the same piece of memory each time.

I guess you want to move some or all of the variable declarations at the start of the loop, to being before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have `abc` declared in the `while(q--)` loop.

This means each iteration of the loop has its own uninitialized fresh copy of `abc`, not related to the previous iteration. Accessing any position of `abc` before initializing it is undefined behavior. That's what the `if(c == '?')` branch does.

Move the declaration out of the loop.